# JavaScript doesn't work properly when a variable's value goes more than 99

Tags: javascript

I have two variable `number,number 1` and a if condition which compares these numbers. Here is the code of If condition:

```
if(number1<number){
    alert("Passing marks can never be greater than Maximum marks!");
    document.getElementById('pass_marks').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
}
```

If the value of number is 10 and value of number1 is 99 then this condition works fine, but if the value of number is 10 and value of number is 100 then this condition gets executed Third and most weird case is if value of number is 100 and value of number1 is 101 then this condition again works fine.
How this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your numbers are numbers and not strings ? Look for "number parsing in JavaScript".

Comment: Please add script that reading the number

Comment: Please show the code where you assign the value to number,number 1

Comment: `if(parseInt(number1) < parseInt(number))` and don't name Your variable number1, number2, number3....

Comment: The code should work if `number` and `number1` are really numbers. So just check them for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Try JavaScript parseInt() Function